# Issue adding date to new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a table where I have to create 2 columns named DOB and DOJ(date of joining)

I have created this

```
CREATE TABLE PROGRAMMER (
    PNAME VARCHAR(20),
    DOB DATE,
    DOJ DATE,
    GENDER VARCHAR,
    PROF1 VARCHAR,
    PROF2 VARCHAR,
    SALARY INT
)
```

Now when I try to put in values:

```
INSERT INTO PROGRAMMER
VALUES
('ANAND',1966/04/12,1992/04/21,'M','PASCAL','BASIC',3200)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 75 Operand type clash: int is
> incompatible with date

I was expecting this:

```
ANAND 12-Apr-66 21-Apr-92 M PASCAL BASIC 3200
```

Comment: Date strings should be quoted. `1966/04/12` is just a mathematical equation (resulting in `40.958333333333336`)

Comment: and like '1966-04-12', not with slashes

Comment: also, your error indicates you are using SQL Server, _not_ MySQL

Comment: you need to add mm-dd-yyyy in date field of insert query..

Comment: @Philisonstrike Operands are integers, so server performs integer division, and the result is 40.

Comment: Avoid using format like `mm-dd-yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd` for date. The safe format is `yyyymmdd` regardless or regional or language settings

Comment: You should always specify the length of your varchars - else do you know how much data they can store by default?

Comment: And you should always explicitly list the the columns your are inserting into.

Comment: Also, avoid the UPPERCASE naming of columns / tables. The COBOL days are over!

Comment: @MihirBangia this is 100% wrong. There's absolutely no reason to use ambiguous localized date literals

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO PROGRAMMER VALUES
('ANAND','1966/04/12','1992/04/21','M','PASCAL','BASIC',3200)
```

You were almost there.